# How do I tell BizTalk to accept an incoming namespace?

Tags: xml, namespaces, biztalk, biztalk-2013

I am receiving an XML file over a webservice and using BizTalk for the transformation. I have the incoming scheme set up to match the nodes, but the Test Map command keeps failing. The file, as it comes in, has a namespace at the beginning of each element, e.g. . I have saved a copy of this file (and removed all but two entries) so that I can test.

When I run the test, I get

> error btm1044: Input validation error: The element 'Report_Data' in namespace 'urn:com.X.X/X_X_-_X' has invalid child element 'Report_Entry' in namespace 'urn:com.X.X/X_X_-_X'. List of possible elements expected: 'Report_Entry'.

If I run the test on a copy of the same file where I've taken out the wd: namespace throughout, I do not get this error. How do I tell BizTalk that this XML uses the namespace wd:?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open the schema in the xsd editor and select the "`<Schema>`" node above the root in the Schema tree. Then go to the properties and find "elementFormDefault". Set it to **qualified** instead of the default.

This should automatically update your map to expect nodes in that namespace, rather than nodes without a namespace.

Comment: Sorry for the delay in acceptance. Other projects have taken priority, but my namespace test file is now loading without error.